# Ionic List class cant be scrolled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

**Note** : The end goal is to create a sticky header & footer, with scroll able list between them

Im creating a page with static header & footer, and with scrollable list between them.

The `list` is scrollable in the browser (`ionic serve`) but not working in android device

This is the `index`:

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-side-menus>
      <ion-side-menu-content>
        <div class="bar bar-header" id="img_header_container">
          <img class="title" id="img_header" src="img/icon.png"/>
        </div>
          <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-side-menu-content>
    </ion-side-menus>

    <div class="bar bar-footer">
      <div class="title"><p id="footer">No copyrights intended. Copyrights belong to their respective owners</p></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And this is the `js` :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    } 
  });
})
```

And this is the content :

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <div>
            <ul class="list">
               <li class="item">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

What should i do to make the `ul` scrollable on the **android device**?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: can you make a plunker ?

Comment: This link will help you http://timonweb.com/posts/improve-ionics-performance-in-android-with-native-scrolls/

Answer (score 1):

this may work for you:

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item>
     hello
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this lines of  code,

**index.html**

```
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {

    // Enable native scrolls for Android platform only,
    // as you see, we're disabling jsScrolling to achieve this.
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
    }

});
```

[**Refer**](http://timonweb.com/posts/improve-ionics-performance-in-android-with-native-scrolls/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The list still cant be scrolled

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for all help.

Im sorry the root problem is not the un-scrollable list, but a header that somehow push all of elements below it. Hence, my scroll stucks and looks like can not be scrolled.